# Vulkan win32_surface creation failure

Tags: visual-c++, vulkan

Seeking to learn and use vulkan, I have followed several examples and had success with them, however once I apply what I know in the context(engine) desired, things are not working as they should or at all.

I'm running into several issues, but the one that is explicitly blocking me is surface creation for win32 type.

context:  windows application, x64, using HWND windows, using Vulkan API Version: 1.0.65, built with VisStudio2015 using VC tools 120 (c++11) on a win 7 x64 OS

order of operations: program start -> create HWND window -> create vulkan instance -> create vulkan surface -> fail

Include setup:

```
#if defined(_WIN32)
#define VK_USE_PLATFORM_WIN32_KHR
#endif
#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>
```

Window creation (hInstance var is set by WinMain entry):

```
GAppWindow = CreateWindowEx( WS_EX_APPWINDOW, *WindowClassName, *Name, WindowStyle, WindowPosX, WindowPosY, WindowWidth, WindowHeight, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL );
```

Instance creation:

```
VkInstance instance;
VkSurfaceKHR surface;

if (enableValidationLayers && !checkValidationLayerSupport())
{ appError("Validation layers requested but not available!"); }

VkApplicationInfo appInfo = {};
appInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
appInfo.pApplicationName = "Hello Triangle";
appInfo.applicationVersion = 1;
appInfo.pEngineName = "No Engine";
appInfo.engineVersion = 1;
appInfo.apiVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);

uint32_t ReqExtensionCount = 0;
std::vector<const char*> ReqExtensions = GetRequiredInstanceExtensions(ReqExtensionCount);

VkInstanceCreateInfo createInfo = {};
createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
createInfo.pApplicationInfo = &appInfo;
createInfo.enabledExtensionCount = ReqExtensionCount;
createInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = ReqExtensionCount ? ReqExtensions.data() : NULL;
createInfo.enabledLayerCount = 0; 
createInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = NULL;

if (enableValidationLayers)
{
    createInfo.enabledLayerCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(validationLayers.size());
    createInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = validationLayers.data();
} 

if (vkCreateInstance(&createInfo, NULL, &instance) != VK_SUCCESS)
{ appError("Failed to create instance!"); }
```

note that ReqExtensions were "VK_KHR_surface", and "VK_KHR_win32_surface".

Surface creation:

```
#if defined(VK_USE_PLATFORM_WIN32_KHR)
VkWin32SurfaceCreateInfoKHR surfaceInfo = {};
surfaceInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_WIN32_SURFACE_CREATE_INFO_KHR;
surfaceInfo.pNext = NULL;
surfaceInfo.flags = 0;
surfaceInfo.hinstance = hInstance;
surfaceInfo.hwnd = GAppWindow;

VkResult result = vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR(instance, &surfaceInfo, NULL, &surface);
if(result != VK_SUCCESS)
{
    appError("Failed to create Win32 surface");
    return 1;
}
#endif
```

result is: VK_ERROR_EXTENSION_NOT_PRESENT

However according to vulkaninfo my system has the following:

Instance Extensions     count = 11
VK_EXT_debug_report                 : extension revision  9
VK_EXT_display_surface_counter      : extension revision  1
VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2: extension revision  1
VK_KHR_get_surface_capabilities2    : extension revision  1
VK_KHR_surface                      : extension revision 25
VK_KHR_win32_surface                : extension revision  6
VK_KHX_device_group_creation        : extension revision  1
VK_KHR_external_fence_capabilities  : extension revision  1
VK_KHR_external_memory_capabilities : extension revision  1
VK_KHR_external_semaphore_capabilities: extension revision  1
VK_NV_external_memory_capabilities  : extension revision  1

and

Presentable Surfaces:
GPU id : 0 (GeForce GTX 980)
Surface type : VK_KHR_win32_surface
Formats: count = 2
B8G8R8A8_UNORM
B8G8R8A8_SRGB
Present Modes: count = 3
FIFO_KHR
FIFO_RELAXED_KHR
MAILBOX_KHR

So I am stumped as to why it says its not present...

Comment: May I assume you have properly functioning validation layers (and what do they say)? Which command returns that `VK_ERROR_EXTENSION_NOT_PRESENT` result? What is the value of `ReqExtensionCount`? Do you even reach the surface creation (why do you show that code?)?

Comment: No, validation layer is nonfunctioning, when it is enabled I get an unhandled exception inside vkCreateInstance.  ReqExtensions are "VK_KHR_surface", and "VK_KHR_win32_surface".  Yes it reaches surface creation, the VK_ERROR is the return value of vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR.

Comment: What is the value of `ReqExtensionCount`? And what is the impl of `GetRequiredInstanceExtensions`?

Comment: The value is 2.  All that is being done in that function is this:
 `ReqInstExtensions.push_back(VK_KHR_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME);
#if defined(VK_USE_PLATFORM_WIN32_KHR)
 ReqInstExtensions.push_back(VK_KHR_WIN32_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME);
#endif `

Comment: Well, there's not much surface area for a bug. It has to be the `GetRequiredInstanceExtensions`... Maybe make a `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_api_dump` log to see which values the driver actually gets.